# Vuetify change text Rows per page text in v-data-table's footer

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm working with v-data-tables of Vuetify and....

I want to change this text:

[image]

I have added this code but it isn't working:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `'items-per-page-text':'products per page'`:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="5"
  item-key="name"
  class="elevation-1"
  :footer-props="{
    showFirstLastPage: true,
    firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
    lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
    prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
    nextIcon: 'mdi-plus',
    'items-per-page-text':'products per page'
  }"
></v-data-table>
```

Please check this [`example`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/PoZPPQx)

Comment: thank you! another word i want to change is: 'of'. do you know how to change it?

Comment: there's a property called `page-text` which has by default `$vuetify.dataFooter.pageText` as value but i don't know how could i change it

Comment: I've been reading about that property... If I achieve It i will tell you

Comment: Thanks, i was trying something like `'page-text':'$vuetify.dataFooter.pageText'.replace('of','de')` but with no success

Comment: I got it! i had to add another template using v-slot footer.page-text: '<template v-slot:footer.page-text="items">
                                    {{ items.pageStart }} - {{ items.pageStop }} de {{ items.itemsLength }}
                                </template>'

Answer (score 9):

The correct prop for Vuetify 2.X is **items-per-page-text**:

```html
<v-data-table
  :footer-props="{itemsPerPageText: 'Rows count'}"
></v-data-table>
```

Comment: Your solution has worked for me perfectly, but I am still having one part without translation. I have two pages and I see "of" when it should be "de" (spanish). What is the property for that topic?

Comment: @inane in your case it should be `:footer-props="{ pageText: '{0}-{1} de {2}' }`

Answer (score 6):

```html
<template v-slot:[`footer.page-text`]="items"> 
  {{ items.pageStart }} - {{ items.pageStop }} de {{ items.itemsLength }}
</template>
```

Comment: What’s the benefit of this approach over the approaches established by the existing answers?

Answer (score 4):

The best way I've ever found is [language localization in the Vuetify configuration](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/).

```js
import en from "vuetify/lib/locale/en";
    
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      options: {/*...*/},
      light: {/*...*/},
      dark: {/*...*/},
    },
  },
  lang: {
    locales: { en },
      current: "en",
  },
});
```

The above configuration causes all the Vuetify components (`v-data-table`) to be language localized.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, at least in version 3.3.9:

```
<VDataTable :pageText="'{0}-{1} de {2}'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the "{start}-{end} of {total}, here's what I did: (the others solution didn't work)

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
        v-model:page="page"
        v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :items-per-page-text="$t('table.itemsPerPage')"
        :page-text="pageText"
></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
    // Inside component definition
    data() {
        return {
            items: [], // Array to show in the table
            page: 1,
            itemsPerPage: 5,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        pageText(): string {
            const total = this.items.length
            const startInterval = (this.page - 1)*this.itemsPerPage+1
            const endInterval = Math.min(this.page*this.itemsPerPage, total)
            const interval = `${startInterval}-${endInterval}`
            return this.$t('table.pageText', {interval: interval, total:total})
        }
    },
</script>
```

And in my translation files, I have

en.json

```
{
    "table": {
        "itemsPerPage": "Items per page",
        "pageText": "{interval} of {total}"
    }
}
```

fr.json

```
{
    "table": {
        "itemsPerPage": "Items par page",
        "pageText": "{interval} de {total}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple in version 3.5.6:

```
<v-data-table
  items-per-page-text="products per page"
/>
```